# How can I convert an xml into xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to convert the xml below into xslt:

```
<object>
  <content type="me">myname</content>
  <content type="you">yourname</content>
  <content type="me">myothername</content>
</object>
```

This one the xslt that I wrote, the condition is that the attribute value must be 'me' and the value of the node content must be 'myname', but it is not returning anything. What can be wrong?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="object/content[@type='me' and text()='myname']"/>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your XSLT isn't syntically correct. The `value-of` statement should be `<xsl:value-of select="object/content[@type='me' and text()='myname']" />`. Having said that, can you show the output you are actually expecting here? Thanks

Comment: Current output after fix suggested by @TimC will be `<object>myname</object>`. Is it expected or do you want `<object><content type="me">myname</content></object>`?

Comment: With the xml input, I wrote the xpath expression: 
 `/object/content[@type='me' and text()='myname']`
 and the xpath result is: `Element='<content type="me">myname</content>''`. I would like to transform the xpath result in xsl file.

Comment: @Artemyvysotsky I want `<object><content type="me">myname</content></object>`

Comment: use `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:value-of`

Comment: It's unclear what it means to you to "convert" XML input into XSLT. How is the desired XSLT document (which is itself XML, too) related to the original document?

Comment: What I want is to return, in xslt, the node content of field only if type='me' and text()='myname'. But my code below is not returning anything.                                                              
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:value-of select="object/content[@type='me' and text()='myname']"/>
        </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't edit the code above

Comment: As Artemy Vysotsky said, you should use `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:value-of` if you want a copy of the node, rather than just the node content. See http://xsltransform.net/3MvmrAG for example.